# digest authentication dosen't work in libcurl 7.43.0

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl

I used the following code C to make digest authentication with my http server.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, user_id);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, passwd);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC|CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
```

my http client (libcurl) recieve http 401 and do not proceed to the digest authentication.
it works for older version.

I also retried with the following command:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# curl --data {"red":"00"} --digest -u "admin:admin" "http://192.168.1.200:8
080/openacs/acs"
<html><head><title>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA</h3></body></html>root@OpenWrt:~#
```

and it dosen't work.

what i'm missing?

Comment: What if you send a request to http://httpbin.org/ (see the digest-auth endpoint)?

Comment: always the same problem, i use liburl 0.38 and openssl 1.0.1f

Comment: For some reason(s) [httpbin.org requires cookies](https://github.com/Runscope/httpbin/issues/124) to be set... So you should run something like: `curl --digest -u foo:bar --cookie-jar jar.txt http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/foo/bar` (feel free to add the `--libcurl out.c` option to generate the libcurl equivalent code).